# Syntax error, unexpected tLABEL, expecting ')' (SyntaxError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, syntax-error, sendgrid-ruby

### Environment

- Ruby **[1.9.3p547]**
- Rails **[3.2.22.5]**
- sendgrid-ruby **[4.0.8]**

I used sendgrid-ruby gem in my application whenever I run rails server it's giving me below error which comes from gems/sendgrid-ruby-4.0.8/lib/sendgrid/client.rb:17

> /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@demo/gems/sendgrid-ruby-4.0.8/lib/sendgrid-ruby.rb:1:in
>   `require_relative':
>   /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@demo/gems/sendgrid-ruby-4.0.8/lib/sendgrid/client.rb:17:
>   syntax error, unexpected tLABEL, expecting ')' (SyntaxError)
>       def initialize(api_key: nil, host: nil, request_head...
>                              ^ /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@demo/gems/sendgrid-ruby-4.0.8/lib/sendgrid/client.rb:17:
>   Can't assign to nil ...   def initialize(api_key: nil, host: nil,
>   request_headers: ... ...                               ^
>   /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@demo/gems/sendgrid-ruby-4.0.8/lib/sendgrid/client.rb:17:
>   Can't assign to nil ...ialize(api_key: nil, host: nil,
>   request_headers: nil, versio... ...                               ^
>   /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@demo/gems/sendgrid-ruby-4.0.8/lib/sendgrid/client.rb:17:
>   Can't assign to nil ...ost: nil, request_headers: nil, version: nil)

I checked the same file and same line of gem sengrid-ruby.
it has below the line

```
def initialize(api_key: nil, host: nil, request_headers: nil, version: nil)
```

if I replace this to below it isn't giving me.

```
def initialize(api_key, host, request_headers, version)
```

is this syntax error of rails or ruby related version? 
There are other lots of error which contain the same syntax in other gems. 
What should I do with this type of syntax errors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keyword arguments require Ruby's version 2.0.0 or higher. https://thoughtbot.com/blog/ruby-2-keyword-arguments

Comment: if i used ruby version `1.9.3p547` then gem `sendgrid-ruby` should also take version based on ruby version. right?

Comment: Nope, they wrote the code with a specific ruby's version

Comment: Look at the link. Each version has a specific `REQUIRED RUBY VERSION`

Comment: I'd try version 3.0.3 for sendgrid-ruby gem

Comment: yes, i checked but look at this `https://rubygems.org/gems/sendgrid-ruby/versions` for version 3.0.4 ruby version should be 2.2 or higher but for gem version 3.0.3 ruby version should be higher then 0.0 .

Comment: Yes, I saw that. Try 3.0.3, it seems the last one before they had used ruby 2.2

Comment: Yes, that might happen. but it should take version 3.0.3 . based on ruby version.

Comment: You choose the versions of the gems. It's not something automatic

Comment: I used version 3.0.3, then also it's giving me the same syntax error. `  * sendgrid-ruby (3.0.3)
`

Comment: Change tag, and see if they used keyword arguments or not. In fact it seems they used even in 3.0.3. but older versions not

Comment: You can see the code for a specific tag. And tags match to versions usually. You can see if they use keyworkd arguments for a specific version.